# MySQL: Get resultset based on a match criteria (pattern like structure)

Tags: mysql, pattern-matching

I only want to display results based on a certain match criteria (ONLY the results that follows that pattern)

This is my expectation
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MrgH.jpg)

I expect a result set with ID 1 to 5, and 12-16 in that sequence or order only as shown below

```
ID  W1  W2  W3  W4  W5  
1   1   43  72  10  33  
2   61  38  16  68  51  
3   80  54  62  87  45  
4   73  39  64  77  22  
5   49  82  32  56  41  

12  1   43  72  10  33  
13  61  38  16  68  51  
14  80  54  62  87  45  
15  73  39  64  77  22  
16  49  82  32  56  41
```

and this is what I have tried

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.W1, T1.W2, T1.W3, T1.W4, T1.W5

FROM drvdb.scores t1
JOIN drvdb.scores t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID

WHERE (T1.W1 ='1' AND T1.W2 = '43' AND T1.W3 = '72' AND T1.W4 = '10' AND T1.W5 = '33')
OR (T2.W1 ='61' AND T2.W2 = '38' AND T2.W3 = '16' AND T2.W4 = '68' AND T2.W5 = '51')
OR (T2.W1 ='80' AND T2.W2 = '54' AND T2.W3 = '62' AND T2.W4 = '87' AND T2.W5 = '45')
OR (T2.W1 ='73' AND T2.W2 = '39' AND T2.W3 = '64' AND T2.W4 = '77' AND T2.W5 = '22')
OR (T2.W1 ='49' AND T2.W2 = '82' AND T2.W3 = '32' AND T2.W4 = '56' AND T2.W5 = '41')

GROUP BY T1.ID
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT T1.W1, T1.W2, T1.W3, T1.W4, T1.W5) = 1
```

I have tried several queries, I still end up with the same undesired results

i want row 1 because it is exactly 1/43/72/10/33 AND is followed by a row 61/38/16/68/51 AND is followed by 3 rows with 80/54/62/87/45 AND 4th row with 73/39/64/77/22 AND the 5th row /49/82/32/56/41 in that order.I want the query to return results based on that hierarchy or rank.
 within my table i only have two of such hierarchy

Isn’t there a way around this? Is this impossible? I have been stuck on this for the past two months trying to figure out how best I can do this...my back just aches. 
Now is time to call for help.
I’m new to SQL and trying to get acquainted with this language

any ideas on how to go about this would be much appreciated

This is my script file

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `drvdb`;
USE `drvdb`;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `scores` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `W1` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `W2` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `W3` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `W4` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `W5` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `W1` (`W1`),
  KEY `W2` (`W2`),
  KEY `W3` (`W3`),
  KEY `W4` (`W4`),
  KEY `W5` (`W5`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;



INSERT INTO `scores` (`ID`, `W1`, `W2`, `W3`, `W4`, `W5`) VALUES
    (1, '1', '43', '72', '10', '33'),
    (2, '61', '38', '16', '68', '51'),
    (3, '80', '54', '62', '87', '45'),
    (4, '73', '39', '64', '77', '22'),
    (5, '49', '82', '32', '56', '41'),
    (6, '68', '8', '30', '35', '1'),
    (7, '20', '21', '22', '23', '24'),
    (8, '61', '38', '16', '68', '51'),
    (9, '1', '43', '72', '10', '33'),
    (10, '80', '54', '62', '87', '45'),
    (11, '49', '82', '32', '56', '41'),
    (12, '1', '43', '72', '10', '33'),
    (13, '61', '38', '16', '68', '51'),
    (14, '80', '54', '62', '87', '45'),
    (15, '73', '39', '64', '77', '22'),
    (16, '49', '82', '32', '56', '41'),
    (17, '61', '38', '16', '68', '51'),
    (18, '80', '54', '62', '87', '45'),
    (19, '49', '82', '32', '56', '41'),
    (20, '61', '38', '16', '68', '51');
```

Comment: What are the rules that you want to apply? Say, why is not row with id=9 in the expected results?

Comment: @ forpas because i only want to extract a particular pattern which is 1 to 5 and 12 to 16 is the only sets that matches that criteria. id  9-10-11 doesn't  make the pattern complete..but anyways if i could get a query to match ID 9-10-11 in that order i would settle for that..i hope u get me...like extract the results in a more indexed format. A

Comment: *1 to 5 and 12 to 16 is the only sets that matches that criteria* what criteria? Do I miss something?

Comment: @ forpas okay this may be much simple lets just say i want to return  just ID 1 AND 2 ONLY....LETS SAY  WHERE (W1 ='1' AND W2 = '43' AND W3 = '72' AND W4 = '10' AND W5 = '33') OR (W1 ='61' AND W2 = '38' AND W3 = '16' AND W4 = '68' AND W5 = '51') my problem is how do i get rid of the OR so i can join these two rows ...ID1 and ID 2...in a more vertical way, like anywhere you find ID1 and ID 2 return those results....please be tolerant English is not my first language

Comment: You need to simplify your question. You should not describe your problem as "how do i get rid of the OR so i can join these two rows" - this assumes that getting rid of the ORs a) solves your actual problem and b) is enough to describe your task to us to know how to get rid of the ORs. Both is likely not true. You need to describe your criteria/why you want specific rows. Guessing here, you want row 1 because it is exactly 1/43/72/10/33 AND is followed by a row 61/38/16/68/51 AND is followed by 3 rows with xxx. And the 4 following rows. Try to break it down to something like this.

Comment: @solarflare exactly the way  i want it ''Guessing here, you want row 1 because it is exactly 1/43/72/10/33 AND is followed by a row 61/38/16/68/51 AND is followed by 3 rows with xxx. And the 4 following rows''. just don't know how to put it...this is exactly what I'm looking for